# Center Align UIImageview and Large UILabel AutoLayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`. Label has greater height than image, so I want to center align Y position for both.

Here is original case:

[image]

When I apply **Center Y** from image to label, label content is truncated.

[image]

Please can someone guide me for correct constraints... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Storyboard Image]

I am using the setup above in my storyboard. A `UIImageView` on the left and a `UITextView` on the right; setup in a `UIViewController`. I setup my constraints like this:

`UIImageView`

- Width Equals: // Whatever you want
- Height Equals: // Whatever you want
- Align Center Y: Text View
- Leading Space to Superview: 16
- Trailing Space to Text View: 8

`UITextView`

- Align Center Y: Image View
- Trailing Space to Superview: 16
- Leading Space to Image View: 8
- Top Space to Top Layout Guide: 16
- Height Equals: // Whatever you want; this will change

The center Y constraint will keep the `UIImageView` centered with the `UITextView`. The top space constraint on the `UITextView` is what will set the vertical positioning for the views. The height constraint on the `UITextView` is where the dynamic height portion comes in. Make an outlet to your view controller for the `UITextView` and the text view height constraint. Also set yourself as the text view's delegate. This will allow us to change everything dynamically as text in the text view is changed.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textView.delegate = self
    }

    func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {
        // Ask the text view how much size it needs to fit its content if it has to 
        // fit in its current width but can grow vertically as much as it needs
        let sizeToFitIn = CGSizeMake(textView.bounds.size.width, CGFloat(MAXFLOAT))
        let newSize = self.textView.sizeThatFits(sizeToFitIn)
        self.textViewHeight.constant = newSize.height
    }
}
```

Comment: I had aligned imageview with top layout as well, that is why imageview wasn't able to align center with label. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a center constraint if I want to center something because it doesn't work for me always either, as you said. What i do is i add a constraint for leading space and trailing space for X centering and top space and bottom space for Y centering.

That would center your label with 30px space on the left and right side. If you want to use the entire space just make the constant to 0. (For Y just change the other two --> Note to activate the constraint you have to click on the red line)

[image]